# Scale elements on page, not page (change pixel density)

Tags: polymer, meta-tags

I'm running a hybrid app and I'm testing it on a Nexus 7 right now. I'm using Polymer for the elements, mostly with default or close to default styling. The elements, like for example paper-fab oder paper-button are displayed far too small. Of course I could change all of their sizes, but isn't there some setting like a meta tag, to change the scale. Setting the initial scale does not work, since it scales the entire page. I only want the individual elements to scale larger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'scale'?

```
transform: scale(2);
```

Note that you should try have a definite height and width before using this, and it might cause a few layout issues but it's nothing which some quick css can't fix.

**Edit:**

On second thoughts what's wrong with:

```
paper-fab, paper-button {
  width: *Your width here*;
  height: *Your height here*;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Add the css below to your project and the elements should automatically scale to the width and height you assign.

```
paper-fab {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

paper-fab::shadow core-icon {
  margin: calc(100% * 2/7);
  width: calc(100% * 3/7);
  height: calc(100% * 3/7);
}
```

Comment: Yes, well what I've done for now is just scale everything with less, setting a scale value in a variable and scaling font sizes and other settings with this value. The problem with changing the width for the paper-fab doesn't work. You'd have to dive deep in the shadow dom and find the right elements to make larger. I used scale instead, as you suggested. I was hoping there'd be a general setting, that simply makes every element appear smaller or bigger.

Comment: Check the edit. It should be the fix you're looking for.